# Trigger Eclipse plugin menu-entry programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've got this question: I have an menu entry in my Eclipse plugin. It has a handler which extends `AbstractHandler` and overrides `execute()` which takes an `ExecutionEvent` parameter.

Now what I want to do is to trigger this function when something specific happens. May someone tell me how to do it?

I guess I have to create a `ExecutionEvent` on my own somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `IHandlerService` to execute the command that the handler handles, which will call your handler:

```java
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand("command id", event);
```

There is another variant of `executeCommand` which takes a `ParameterizedCommand` if you need to pass command parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding for potential readers: event can simply be null.